# Acerca de imprimir con printf un boolean en Java

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Java y estoy realizando un ejercicio dónde he de imprimir por pantalla con `printf` una variable booleana. La variable en cuestión es género, que puede ser M o F.

Veamos la inicialización de la variable:

boolean sexo = true; //Le he puesto true porque me daba error Netbeans y no me ponía que estaba inicializada, pero no sé cómo poner que a true le corresponde M y que a false le corresponde F.

System.out.printf ("El valor de la variable sexo es %s%n", sexo);//Creo que estaría bien así, pero fallo en que supongo que así me imprimirá true, pero no M, que es lo que yo quiero, porque no sé cómo programar qué cosa le corresponde a true y qué cosa le corresponde a false.

Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 2):

Una variable de tipo `boolean` solo puede ser igual a `true` o `false` nada más. Para hacer lo que quieres, debes apoyarte de condicionales o de otros mecanismos para que M sea `true` y F sea `false` o viceversa.

Ejemplo:

```
boolean sexoM = true;

        if (sexoM) {
            // Entra aquí solamente porque sexoM es true
            System.out.println("M");
        } else {
            System.out.println("F");
        }
```

A un `boolean` no puedes asignarle otra cosa que no sea `true` o `false`.

Otra forma:

```
boolean sexoM = true;
boolean sexoF = false;

        if (sexoM) {
            System.out.println("Soy M");
        }

        if (sexoF) {
            // No entra aquí porque sexoF es false
            System.out.println("No soy F");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la forma más sencilla de resolver esto sería con un [**Operador ternario**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Un Operador Ternario en su forma más básica se presenta así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen, evalúa una `Expresión booleana`, si la misma es verdadera, tomaría lo que le asignemos antes de los dos puntos `:`, y si es false, tomaría lo que le asignemos después de los dos puntos.

En este caso la evaluación sería muy sencilla, por ejemplo:

```
    statusSexo = (sexoM) ? "M" : "F";
```

Aquí la variable `statusSexo` adquirirá el valor `M` si `sexoM` es `true`, de lo contrario, adquirirá el valor `F`.

El programa quedaría entonces así:

```
    boolean sexoM = true;
    String statusSexo = (sexoM) ? "M" : "F";  
    System.out.println(statusSexo);
```

Aquí tendrás en pantalla:

```
M
```

Hacemos otra prueba cambiando el valor de la variable boolena a `false`:

```
    boolean sexoM = false;
    String statusSexo = (sexoM) ? "M" : "F";  
    System.out.println(statusSexo);
```

Aquí tendrás por pantalla:

```
F
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando un condicional podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
if(sexo) {
    Char genero = 'M';
} else {
    Char genero = 'F';
}
```

Después ya puedes mostrar por pantalla el resultado de dicha condicional:

```
System.out.printf("%c %n", genero);
```